# Make the Link NOT Editable asp.net c# Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web

I have a page there is a button that generates a Link like this.

```
  private string GenerateLINK(string NameID)
    {

        string NameID= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FName"] + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LName"];

        string sQS = ID+ "|" + ClientName;

        var xCrypto = new CryptoServer();
        string Vector= null;
        string sEncrypted = null;

        xCrypto.Encrypt3DES(sQS, ref sEncrypted, ref Vector);

        string sURL = sEncrypted + "#######" + Vector;
        sURL = Server.UrlEncode(sURL);
        sURL = "https://www.Page.aspx?s=" + sURL;
        return sURL;
    }
```

This then gets sent to a user who clicks on it and goes to a page. 
Now the issue is I take the link like this and DCode it.

```
   private void DecryptQuerystring()
{
    var sQS = Request.QueryString["s"];
    sQS = Server.UrlDecode(sQS);

    var idelim = sQS.IndexOf("###X####", StringComparison.Ordinal);

    var sIv = sQS.Substring(idelim + 8);
    sQS = sQS.Substring(0, idelim);

    var xCrypto = new ICECrypto.CryptoServer();
    sQS = xCrypto.Decrypt3DES(sQS, sIv);

    string sID = sQS.Substring(0, sQS.IndexOf("|"));
    studentID = sID;
    Name = sQS.Substring(sQS.IndexOf("|") + 1); 
    Welcome.InnerText = "Welcome " + sQS.Substring(sQS.IndexOf("|") + 1);

}
```

The Problem is when the User gets there and if he puts in any word in the link it breaks the whole page showing the Server Error. I want user to NOT to be able to Edit the Link insert any thing in it. Any clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your server should gracefully handle unknown urls by returning 404 error code to the user. If your decode fails due to bad input, you should gracefully handle it and return a 404 to the user.

Comment: Riv I don't think you got the point by the way the 404 Code only works when the interred Link is not a page of your web-Site My Link is valid its that value that's Encrypted stored in Query string i was talking about if user types in that Query String any thing that's not a valid Encrypted value that's where it breaks. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is funny but I am answering my own question maybe someone else could use it. 
So where I am doing the Decryption of the QueryString() i put in the word

```
Try {
    // Do the Decryption here
}
Catch(Exception ex) {
    // if any thing goes wrong in that Try it will hit here and then i will show error 404
}
```